# Why is xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" appearing grey and selector shown as an error suddenly?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, schema, android-appcompat

http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&quot; is appearing grey and select is an error.">

**Why is this so? This is happening suddenly when I tried to add a new xml file in drawable.The xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" is appearing grey and select is an error.**

**This error is now happening everywhere, xmlns uri is not registered and etc. errors are also appearing, I checked for some answers and their suggestions didn't work**

I am using appcompat 7 21.0.2, android studio release candidate 1. This is happening suddenly and I can't get it to go away
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmxc7.png

Comment: Where is the XML file? The screenshot doesn't show it in `drawable`.